# indexing strategies

Tags: database-design, index, db2, iseries

I am confused by indexing strategies advocated by one of the database products. Database is "DB2 for i" (iSeries/AS400).

Please see following SQL and index advised by the product for the SQL.  There is no improvement in run time after creating new index. Run time for both cases (without new index and with new index) is 10 ms. Size (disk space) of new index is double the size of existing index (primary key) and probably it will use more system resources (memory). Does anyone see any benefits from the new index based on the SQL in question?

Tables:

```
Invoice ( 30 columns , primary key invoice_id , several million records)
customer ( 20 columns , primary key cust_code, half million records)
```

FK for cust_code is defined on invoice table.

Query:

```
select i.col1, i.col2, ..., i.col20,
c.col1, c.col2,....,c.col10
from invoice i, customer c
where i.invoice_id = '123'
and i.cust_code = c.cust_code
```

index advised:

```
Table: invoice Columns : invoice_id, cust_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a need for it, but you can help without creating the index at least in SQL Server

You are joining on invoice..cust_code which is not indexed so that the Database engine will have to do a hash lookup on the table finding all invoices with the correct customer code and then filtering on the invoice id.

By creating and enforcing a foreign key the join will be faster, as the optimizer can safely assume that invoice_id '123' exists for this single customer, but having the suggested index can help the optimizer to find the optimal query plan, a singleton lookup to both the tables, faster.

Comment: Why would the engine have to do a hash lookup? The condition is `where i.invoice_id = '123'` and `invoice_id` is the PK.

Comment: @ypercube I assume this is SQL Server, where  the logical processing order of the sql statement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) processes JOIN before WHERE so the optimzer will have to do more work to come up with a good enough plan. Which would lead to the index suggestion above.

Comment: The logical order of processing though does not forbid the optimizer from using a plan with different order.

Comment: yes, absolutely correct, but the question is why is this index suggested and would it help. The reason for for the index suggestion is the join  clause, the optimizer will most likely use the primary keys and singleton lookups because of the WHERE clause. With out a foreign key though the optimizer has no way of knowing if the particular order is issued to a valid customer. (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-us/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries)

Comment: * Database in question is "DB2 for i" (AS400).

Comment: There is no difference in run time between execution without new index and execution after creating new index.  The actual run time for the query under both conditions is 10 ms. There is no improvement on select due to new index. The new index will only increase the execution cost of insert/delete/update on the table.

Comment: Table invoice has FK defined for cust_code. There is no possibility of having invoices with cust_code that does not exist in customer table.

Comment: @satya, it would be good if you added this info in the question (the FK, the `CREATE TABLE` scripts, the query times, etc.) Also, who or what (tool) suggested the index?

Comment: @ypercube. I mentioned that there was no advantage with new index. I should have elaborated that statement with actual run times in the beginning itself. However, I did not expect that people will assume that database contains invalid data. FK does not really make any difference on run time. "DB2 for i" automatically provides index suggestions for every SQL executed. This feature is part of database itself and there is no way to turn it off :). The reason I did not mention database name or tool details is to find out whether the suggested index makes sense in case of any commercial database.

Comment: @Sporri

<< By creating and enforcing a foreign key the join will be faster >>
The access path is same with or without foreign key and it does not change run time of the SQL in question. Foreign key will not help execution of above SQL in anyway.

Comment: @ypercube

I am curious about needing DDL information for above question. Will it make any difference in execution plan if the remaining columns in both tables are  numeric or varchar or BLOB?

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for the tip. Followed your suggestion and added more details to the question.